# How can I keep checking a folder until it is empty before continuing on with the script

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script will be moving a file from one folder into another folder and needs to wait until that file is consumed by another application before moving the next file.

I've tried a Do...Until and a Do...While, which both failed. I am now attempting to do it with a function that loops on itself.

When I tried the Do...Until and Do...While, it does nothing once I remove the file (powershell window doesn't close and it just sits there). If I try it with the function, it just goes straight through to the end of the script no matter whether there is a file or not.

This is the function:

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Tester1 | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count

Function FoldCheck(){
if ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0){return}else{foldcheck}
}
Write-Host "Empty"
```

This is the Do...Until I tried:

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Tester1 | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count

Do {start-sleep 1}
until ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)

if ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)
{move-item C:\Temp\Tester2\Test2.txt -Destination C:\Temp\Tester1}
else
{Write-Host "failed"
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")}
```

Comment: you need to have the count updated ... you appear to only check it ONCE. [*grin*] you likely otta put a check _inside_ the `do/until` or _inside_ the function call.

Comment: You have it. Should've known this one, I've been caught out before! The drawbacks of not coding often I guess. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Should just re-arrange to

```
do {
   $directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Tester1 | Measure-Object
   $directoryInfo.count
   start-sleep 1
}until ($directoryInfo.count -ne 0)

Write-Host "Folder is empty now."
```